# Cors error with axios using authentication

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am having some trouble with axios once I add authentication.

My api.ts file:

```
import axios from "axios"

export default axios.create({
  baseUrl: "https://someUrl"
})
```

In App.ts i am setting authentication header:

```
import api from api.ts

function App(){
  api.default.header.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`
}
```

And in my apiHooks.ts

```
import api from api.ts
import {useQuery} from "react-query"
const GetSomething = () => {
  const {data, isLoading = useQuery("key", () => {
    return api.get("/api")
  });
  return data?.data
};
export default GetSomething;
```

So when I'm using the hook, I get a Cors error ONLY when turning on authentication.
The error is the following:

> cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at "url"

Answer (score 0):

Try putting "/" at the end of url.
If it doesn't work, please comment.

```
import api from api.ts
import {useQuery} from "react-query"
const GetSomething = () => {
  const {data, isLoading = useQuery("key", () => {
    return api.get("/api/")
  });
  return data?.data
};
export default GetSomething;
```

Personally, I do it as follows

```
import axios from "axios";

const baseURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/";

// axios instance for making requests
export const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: baseURL,
  timeout: 5000,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    accept: "application/json",
  },
});

// request interceptor for adding token
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("access");
    if (token) {
      config.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;
    }
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

and hook:

```
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import { axiosInstance } from "../utils/axios";
const fetchData = () => {
  return axiosInstance.get("/item-list/");
};

export const useData = () => {
  return useQuery("item-list", fetchData);
};
```

Comment: Does not work. I have something like: api.get("/api/users"). Do I have to add special headers?

Comment: It could also be the backend fault. If you are using DRF this can help: https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/

Comment: I am using aws api-gateway.. I will try your solution.

Comment: Your solution did not work unfortunately..

Comment: I dont know apigateway that much ,but I am sure CORS must be enabled on any server. First article I found might help you. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Answer (score -1):

`CORS` has to be enabled on the server where the `API` is running on. CORS added new `HTTP headers` that allow servers to describe the set of origins that are permitted to read that information.

To enable CORS in Rails based application following code should be included in `cors.rb`-

```rb
    Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
    
        resource '*',
          headers: :any,
          methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head],
          expose: ['Access-Token', 'Uid', 'Client']
      end
    end
```